# XCode 4 - Errors building project with undefined symbols for architecture

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm getting the following build error and I have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not entirely sure whether I'm missing a particular framework or not.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_YAJLParser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libem.a(EMDynamicBrandController.o)
      objc-class-ref in libem.a(EMDynamicKeywordsDataSource.o)
      objc-class-ref in libem.a(EMURLEndecaSearchResponse.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It certainly looks like a missing framework but I can't find any reference to those symbols with Google. Can you find those symbols in your code anywhere?

Comment: Found that Framework here: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/ios/YelpAPI/Frameworks/YAJL.framework

Comment: @Marek Sebera: I actually used the YAJLParser git framework and it seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using and including the following Framework and it now builds successfully:

[YAJL Framework](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc/tree/master)

The YAJL framework is an Objective-C framework for the [YAJL](http://lloyd.github.com/yajl/) SAX-style JSON parser.